# Illegal characters in path in -File parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell

Hallo I've got a question, trying to execute command in cmd and I'm getting

```
Copy-Item : Illegal characters in path.
```

Basing on exception stack it looks like cmd is having problem with Prj - www this part. Command looks like this

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File ..\Utils\Deploy.ps1 "\\192.168.1.2\c$\Program Files (x86)\Prj\Prj - www\"
```

Interesting thing is when I launch it using powershell using only

```
 ..\Utils\Deploy.ps1 "\\192.168.1.2\c$\Program Files (x86)\Prj\Prj - www\"
```

It works with no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Change the last ``\`` to ``\\`` (or remove it completely) - cmd will otherwise treat it as an escape sequence for `"`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks! Totally fixed similar for me.